# Java to XML (SOAP) with Smooks using FreeMarker

Tags: java, xml, jboss, smooks

Hey StackOverflow users,

I'm currently working on a SOA Project. As an Application Server I use JBoss 5.1 with JBoss ESB 4.11 deployed.
I try to implement a Web Service which recieves SOAP Messages from Clients and send responses as SOAP messages as well.
When a SOAP message request is recieved by this Web Service I'm using Smooks to transform this message into Java Objects so i can process the request.
When im done processing, I want to transform Java Objects to XML (a SOAP reply), again with Smooks.

I'm stuck on the transformation from Java to XML.
My Action Chain in the `jboss-esb.xml` file looks like this:

```
<services>
  <service name="myWS" description="A Service" category="WS">
        <listeners>
            <jms-listener name="myListener" busidref="myChannel"/>
        </listeners>
        <actions mep="RequestResponse" inXsd="in.xsd" outXsd="out.xsd">
            <!-- Transform incomming SOAP Message into JavaBean objects -->
            <action name="xml2java-transform" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.smooks.SmooksAction">
                <property name="smooksConfig" value="/smooks/smooks-config-soap2java.xml"/>
                <property name="resultType" value="JAVA" />
            </action>

            <action name="processRequest" class="example.soa.ProcessRequest" process="process">
                <property name="config" value="val"/>
            </action>

            <!-- Transform outgoing JavaBean objects into SOAP Message -->
            <action name="java2xml-transform" class="org.jboss.soa.esb.smooks.SmooksAction">
                <property name="smooksConfig" value="/smooks/smooks-config-java2soap.xml"/>
                <property name="reportPath" value="/smooks/report.html"/>
                <property name="resultType" value="STRING" />
            </action>
        </actions>
    </service>
</services>
```

My `smooksConfig` of the second SmooksAction looks like this:

```
<smooks-resource-list   xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                    xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd"
                    xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.4.xsd">

<core:filterSettings type="SAX" defaultSerialization="false"/> 

<resource-config selector="example.JavaObjectMessage">
    <resource>org.milyn.delivery.DomModelCreator</resource>
</resource-config>


<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="example.JavaObjectMessage">
    <!--<ftl:template>/freemarker/acknowledge.flt</ftl:template> -->
    <ftl:template>
        <!-- 
        <sg:Message xmlns:sg="urn:http://example">
            <sg:MessageType>${.vars[example.JavaObjectMessage].messageType}</sg:MessageType>
        </sg:Message >
        -->
    </ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

After the `processRequest` Action is done processing the incomming request it will attatch the `example.JavaObjectMessage` class to the esb message. So the second SmooksAction will have access to this Object.

My question is: how can i access the attributes of the 'example.JavaObjectMessage' in the `smooksConfig`? And to what does the `applyOnElement` refer to in the `flt:tamplate` section?

I already read the Smooks User Guide and in the JBoss Community I posted this question too.
I appreciate any help!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem! I had a hard time to understand the mechanism of how to transform `Java` to `XML` with the `SmooksAction` and im sure i still don't understand everything.
Anyways what i did was:
1. took a closer look at the `SAX` filter within the `smooks-config.xml` file
2. found out, that the `SAX` filter will create an `XML` document with the package name of the     Java Object as root element and all its attributes as child elements.
3. the XML document created by the `SAX` filter can then be used to create a virtual object (in this case a `HashMap`)
4. the `HashMap` can then be used as the input for the FreeMarker template

So my `smooks-config.xml` file looks now like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding='UTF-8'?>
<smooks-resource-list   xmlns="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks-1.1.xsd"
                    xmlns:ftl="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/freemarker-1.1.xsd"
                    xmlns:jb="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/javabean-1.2.xsd"
                    xmlns:core="http://www.milyn.org/xsd/smooks/smooks-core-1.4.xsd">

<resource-config selector="global-parameters">
    <param name="stream.filter.type">SAX</param>
</resource-config>

<jb:bean beanId="message" class="java.util.HashMap" createOnElement="example.JavaObjectMessage">
    <jb:value property="messageType" decoder="String" data="example.JavaObjectMessage/messageType"/>
</jb:bean>

<ftl:freemarker applyOnElement="example.JavaObjectMessage">
    <ftl:template>
    <!--     
        <sg:Message xmlns:sg="urn:http://message">
            <sg:MessageType>${message.messageType}</sg:MessageType>
        </sg:Message>
    --> 
    </ftl:template>
</ftl:freemarker>
</smooks-resource-list>
```

as explained before: first use the `SAX` filter, second create a virtual object (`HashMap` in this case), third: do the templating with free marker